# Copy a cell range in a Google Sheet file to multiple files in the same folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am just wondering if it’s possible to copy a cell range from a Google Sheet file to all other Google Sheet files in the same Google Drive folder?

For example, In the Google Drive folder we have a master template and then all of the other client workbooks (same files that simply contain different data).

Is it possible to copy Sheet1, cell A1 from the master workbook and paste to Sheet1, cell A1 to all of the other files within the folder?

Is this something I could do with a Google Script?

I have been searching but I can't find exactly what I'm looking for.

Kind regards
Peta

Answer (score 2):

1. [openById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyidid) (master)
2. [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) / getValues()
3. [getFolderById(id)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfolderbyidid)
4. [getFiles()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfiles)
5. [open(file)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openfile)
6. [setValue(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue) / setValues(values)

Comment: Perfect answer!